# Ext for commutative Gorenstein algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional commutative Gorenstein $K$-algebra over a field $K$.

> Question 1: Is there an easy example of $A$-modules $M$ and $N$ such that $\mathrm{Ext}_A^1(M,N)=0$ but $\mathrm{Ext}_A^2(M,N) \neq 0$?

I can show that this can not happen for example for $A=KG$, a group algebra of a p-group (doesn't have to be commutative) and noticed that it seems to hold for surprisingly many modules over local rings (but it does not hold for arbitrary non-commutative finite dimensional local algebras).

> Question 2: Let $M=xA$ and $N=yA$ for two elements $x,y \in A$.
> Is there an easy example for $\dim\mathrm{Ext}_A^1(M,N) \neq \dim \mathrm{Ext}_A^1(N,M)$, where dim denotes the vector space dimension over $K$? What about when $x$ and $y$ are monomials in the variables $x_i$ when $A$ is a quotient of $K[x_1,...,x_n]$?

Again the computer is not able to find a simple counterexample yet. This is not true for arbitrary ideals $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Does finite-dimensional mean that $A$ has finite Krull dimension, or that there is some field $k$ such that $A$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I clarified that it is finite dimensional over a field (so Krull dimension zero).